# Is this possible to deploy OSGI bundle into karaf container via script?

Tags: perl, ant, osgi, apache-karaf

I want to deploy the OSGI bundle into karaf container through script file. The script could be PERL or ANT. Here the steps to deploy it into the container.

```
karaf>ssh -p 8101 admin@localhost
Enter password :admin
karaf>osgi:install -s file:<location-file>
karaf>logout
```

I have tried via PERL script but unable to give password in script file itself.

**Is there any alternative way to enter ssh console without password?** Or 
**Is this possible to deploy OSGI bundle via script?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There comes a [client shell](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/start-stop.html#Connect) script, you should be able to pass a "shell script" to it via command line, so no need to use ssh since the client script already does connect to the karaf shell internally.

For scripting with Karaf you might also want to take a look at [Karaf Documentation about scripting](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/console.html#Scripting)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, To run this script, We have to enter into the karaf console right. Do you have any idea, how to enter into karaf console trough script?

Comment: no you can use the bin/client shell script, that will give you the console

Comment: Add a bit of information, you may open a OS shell and issue the command `client -u admin "osgi:install -s file:<location-file>"`